# ferror leads to access violation

Tags: c++

I get an Access Violation when calling `ferror(f)`. The thing is I check that `f` isn't a null pointer. I'm also able to read out of the file, before I get the Access Violation. It happens in the bzip library from http://www.bzip.org, (which is only modified, so that it is possible to build, eg. disable error and remove the multiple main functions).

Here is the my main

```
int main() {
int e = 0;
int *error = &e;
FILE *f = fopen("./test", "r"); //open file
if (f == NULL) {  //Changed, as beforehand both checks happend at the same time
//However the programm passes both checks
    std::cout << "f* is NULL\n";
    exit(1);
}
if (ferror(f)) {
    std::cerr << "Can't open the file " << ferror(f) << '\n';
    exit(1);
}
char *c = char[20];
fread(c, 1, 20, f); // Here we can read succesfully out of the file
std::cout << c;
BZFILE* bzfile = BZ2_bzReadOpen(error, f, 1, 0, NULL, 0); //The failing function call
}
```

Here is the function out of the library which fails:

```
BZFILE* BZ_API(BZ2_bzReadOpen) 
                   ( int*  bzerror, 
                     FILE* f, 
                     int   verbosity,
                     int   small,
                     void* unused,
                     int   nUnused )
{
   bzFile* bzf = NULL;
   int     ret;

   BZ_SETERR(BZ_OK);

   if (f == NULL || //A check in the function itself, which also passes
       (small != 0 && small != 1) ||
       (verbosity < 0 || verbosity > 4) ||
       (unused == NULL && nUnused != 0) ||
       (unused != NULL && (nUnused < 0 || nUnused > BZ_MAX_UNUSED)))
      { BZ_SETERR(BZ_PARAM_ERROR); return NULL; };

   if (ferror(f)) // Here is the access violation
      { BZ_SETERR(BZ_IO_ERROR); return NULL; };
}
```

The specific error is

```
Exception thrown at 0x0003E5C4 in wikiParser.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation executing location 0x0003E5C4.
```

I tried moving the program to a different pc, however the same error still occurs. The pointer isn't NULL; there are two checks for that, and I can call `ferror` myself, without it being an access violation.

Comment: Doesn't look like C.

Comment: 'if(f == NULL || ferror(f))' does not check f for NULL:(

Comment: Besides all the error checks being in mixed up locations, and part of the code being in the wrong language, I wonder if that `c` is supposed to be NUL-terminated

Comment: You have `std::cerr << "Can't open the file " << ferror(f)  << '\n';` — this isn't C; it is C++.  Also, after reporting the error (and while reporting the error), your code goes on to use the faulty `f` as if all was well.  That's not good!

Comment: Could you try running under debugger?

Comment: I tried the debugger, it directly jumps to the error, and the pointer f isn't NULL, also before it fails, I'm able to read from said file stream

Comment: In the debugger, check the value of `f` inside and outside of the BZ2  function. Are they same?

Comment: Yes, only the `_Placeholder=xxxx` changes due to the `fread`

Comment: `char *c = char[20];` ???

Answer (score 3):

```
if(f == NULL || ferror(f)) // Check that f isn't NULL nor has an Error
    std::cerr << "Can't open the file " << ferror(f)  << '\n';
```

In other words, if `f== NULL` then `cerr << ferror(f)`.

No wonder it blows up.

Comment: That is a valid concern, however this is not the part where it fails, it reaches the last function call, with the check beforehand